# How to check If string exists in a multi-dimensional arraylist in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have an arrayList like below. The value in the array are not known.

```
DesignPoints{(0).tag => "Apple"
            (1).tag => "Banana"
            (2).tag => "Carrot"
            (3).tag => "Dates"
and so on
}
```

How can I compare if the arrayList contains specific without looping, since I do have already loops in the code.
E.g I want to check if Carrot is in the ArrayList or not?

Edit:
ArrayList Update

```
Designpoints
(0) "-> object"
SM.Vertex
Tag => "DCUT"
(1) "-> object"
SM.Vertex
Tag => "KCUT"
```

I have this sort of function from which I want to find if those tag exists or not from the arraylist like this

```
If Designpoints(FromNode - 1).tag = "DCUT" And Designpoints(Dcount).tag = "DCUT" And Designpoints(Dcount + 1).tag = "DCUT" Then
                            polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.DrainCut
                            customPolygon.Add(polygon)
                        ElseIf Designpoints(FromNode - 1).tag = "KCUT" And Designpoints(Dcount).tag = "KCUT" And Designpoints(Dcount + 1).tag = "KCUT" Then
                            polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.KerbCut
                            customPolygon.Add(polygon)

                        ElseIf Designpoints(FromNode + 1).tag = "WALL" Then
                            polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.StructureCut
                            customPolygon.Add(polygon)
                        Else

                            polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.Cut
                            customPolygon.Add(polygon)

                        End If
If Designpoints(FromNode - 1).tag = "DCUT" And Designpoints(Dcount).tag = "DCUT" And Designpoints(Dcount + 1).tag = "DCUT" Then
                            polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.DrainCut
                            customPolygon.Add(polygon)
                        ElseIf Designpoints(FromNode - 1).tag = "KCUT" And Designpoints(Dcount).tag = "KCUT" And Designpoints(Dcount + 1).tag = "KCUT" Then
                            polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.KerbCut
                            customPolygon.Add(polygon)

                        ElseIf Designpoints(FromNode + 1).tag = "WALL" Then
                            polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.StructureCut
                            customPolygon.Add(polygon)
                        Else

                            polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.Cut
                            customPolygon.Add(polygon)

                        End If
```

I want to convert it to

```
If Designpoints.ToArray().Any(Function(c) CStr(c.Tag) = "DCUT") Then
                            polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.DrainCut
                            customPolygon.Add(polygon)
                        ElseIf Designpoints.ToArray().Any(Function(c) CStr(c.Tag) = "KCUT") Then
                            polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.KerbCut
                            customPolygon.Add(polygon)
                        ElseIf Designpoints.ToArray().Any(Function(c) CStr(c.Tag) = "WALL") Then
                            polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.StructureCut
                            customPolygon.Add(polygon)
                        Else
                            polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.Cut
                            customPolygon.Add(polygon)

                        End If
```

Comment: Firstly, there's no such thing as a multidimensional `ArrayList`. An array can be multidimensional but a collection could only be equivalent to a jagged array, i.e. a collection of collections, but your isn't even that as far as I can tell.  Secondly, why use an `ArrayList` at all, given that they were made effectively obsolete in 2005 by the `List(Of T)`?

Comment: As for the question, you can use a LINQ query to do basically what a loop does but not write one explicitly in your code. The loop code will actually be more efficient most of the time but the difference will generally be negligible so the succinctness of the LINQ code is preferable, e.g. `If myArrayList.Cast(Of Control)().Any(Funcion(c) CStr(c.Tag) = "Carrot") Then`. I guessed the type of the items to be `Control` because of your use of the `Tag` property but you can cast as whatever type they are. If you use a `List(Of T)` then no cast is required.

Comment: I have updated with what I required to get... I tried cast the error is "Unable to cast object of type 'SM.Vertex' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'."

Comment: OK, I specifically said that I just guessed at type `Control` and if your collection contains some other type then cast as that. Please don't ask about an issue that has already been predicted and the solution provided. It suggests that you're not bothering to actually read the information provided.